# Fill a list from data of the database

Tags: android, sqlite

please I would need your help to figure out, why these code lines do not work.
I would like to fill a list with String elements taken from the database.

This is the mothod fillTheList() which returns a list:

```
public List<String> fillTheList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

//My database is called "ITEMS_" and the first column is called "typeOfItem"
    String[] column = {"typeOfItem"};
    String selection = "SELECT DISTINCT type FROM ITEMS_";

    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getDataCategories("ITEMS_", column, selection);

    if(cursor != null) {
        list.clear();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String type = cursor.getString(1);

                list.add(type);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    Log.d("List", cursor.getString(1));
    return list;
}
```

The getDataCategories() is a mehod of the sqLiteHelper-class

```
public Cursor getDataCategories(String table, String[] columns, String selection )
{
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(true, table, new String[] {String.valueOf(columns)}, selection,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

The error occurs at: 
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getDataCategories("ITEMS_", column, selection); and the logcat is: 
     "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method     'android.database.Cursor SQLiteHelper.getDataCategories(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 0):

The error log indicates that `MainActivity.sqLiteHelper` is `null`. 
I don't know in which class you have `fillTheList()`, but you deal with the issue of filling the list in a wrong way. 
Change `fillTheList()` it like:

```
public List<String> fillTheList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getDataCategories();
    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

As you can see **you must supply a context** for the initialization of SQLiteHelper to fetch the cursor and populate the list. 
Then change `getDataCategories()` to this:

```
public Cursor getDataCategories() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT typeOfItem FROM ITEMS_", null);
}
```

This method uses `rawQuery()` which is simpler and not `query()`. 
I don't know if the name of the column is `typeOfItem` or `type`, so if you need change the sql statement. 
Now you can use `fillTheList()` if first you have a valid `SQLiteOpenHelper` object, say `sqlObject`, like:

```
List<String> list = sqlObject.fillList();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184655/discussion-on-answer-by-forpas-fill-a-list-from-data-of-the-database).

Comment: my table:<br/> *private static final String KEY = "id";<br/>
    private static final String KATEGORIE = "kategorie";<br/>
    private static final String NAME = "name";<br/>
   

    private static final String CREATE_DATA_BANK_ITEMS_ =<br/>

            "CREATE TABLE " + "ITEMS_" + " (" +<br/>
                    KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +<br/>
                    KATEGORIE + "String," +<br/>
                    NAME + " String);";<br/>

    @Override<br/>
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {<br/>
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATA_BANK_ITEMS_);
    }*

Comment: The table has nothing to do with the initialization of the `sqLiteHelper` object, because your code does not call `getDataCategories()` since `sqLiteHelper` is `null`. As I said you must put a breakpoint at the line of the initialization and check what happens.